# Return a value from PHP to HTML

Tags: php, python, html

I am in the process of creating a website and I am using HTML to create a form for the user to enter information. Once the user enters this information, a PHP program reads the input and sends it to a Python program. This python program creates a user database and then returns the user's unique ID number. However, I am not quite sure how to return the value from Python back to HTML via PHP.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

EDIT (I am adding some code):

The HTML is of the form below. You can see that it calls example.php.

```
 <section id="content">


    <div class="shady bott-27"></div>


    <div class="inner clearfix">
        <div class="inner-t">
            <div class="col1">
                         <div class="heading">
                <h3 id="Contact" href="#Contact"><strong><span style="color:#87CEEB">Preliminary Information</span></strong></h3>
                         </div>
             <br>
             </div>

            <div class="col1-2">
            <h4></h4>
                        <form id="contact" method="post" action="example.php">
                          <div>
                            <label>Something*</label> <input id="something" type="text" name="something" />
                          </div>
```

The PHP code is:

```
$something = $_REQUEST["something"];

$command = "python /var/www/html/pythonfile.py";
$command .= " \"$something\" 2>&1";
$pid = popen( $command,"r");
while( !feof( $pid ) )
{
 echo fread($pid, 256);
 flush();
 ob_flush();
 usleep(100000);
}
pclose($pid);
```

?>

And finally, the Python code:

```
def examplepython(something):
#this function creates a new vendor
appID = ....
apiKey = ....
url = ...


ps2 = {"field_1": something}
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Knack-Application-Id": appID,
    "X-Knack-REST-API-Key": apiKey
}

datas = json.dumps(ps2)
req = urllib2.Request(url, datas, headers)

try:
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, ex:
    if ex.fp:
        extra = ex.fp.read()
        print "%s" % extra
    else:
        raise

data = json.loads(f.read())
identification = data["id"]
print "Your ID number is: " + identification
```

Comment: Why is PHP involved? You'll need to post more information and code

Comment: Well, part of my html code is:

<form id="contact" method="post" action="examplefile.php">

I don't know how to call a Python file. Do I just say action="examplepython.py" instead? Or do I include the whole directory for the python file?

Comment: The way you are asking this question is vague, which makes it hard to offer any meaningfully detailed solution. Can you be more specific? What have you tried so far? Show us your code. Are you encountering errors?

Comment: I just made some edits and added some code. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, so I'll try to give the best answer I can in this situation. PHP generates HTML for you, you could use `echo variable_containing_user_ID` which will inject it in your HTML page. Or, if your HTML and PHP are separated in different files, you could use a templating framework like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're spawning the Python process from within your PHP using either [`shell_exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or the [Backtick Operator](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.execution.php), you can just store the result of the Python script in a variable and then use `echo` to send it along to your HTML page:

For example:

```
<?php  
$someVariable = `python yourScript.py param1 param2`;
echo "<div>$someVariable</div>";
?>
```